# Questions about convergence related to Theta functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, theta-functions

Let $H_n$ be the set of matrices $z\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ which are symmetric with a positiv-definite imaginary part.
Let's assume that it is already known and proved that
$\vartheta_a(z)=\sum_{g\in\mathbb{Z}^{m\times n}}e^{\pi i \cdot trace(g^T\cdot a\cdot g \cdot z)}$
(for a symmetric and positiv-definite real matrix $a\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$) is absolutely convergent on $H_n$ and uniformly convergent and bounded on subsets of $H_n$ with $Im(z)\geq y_0$ (where $y_0\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric and positiv-definite real matrix).

Show that $f(w)=\sum_{g\in\mathbb{Z}^{m\times n}}e^{\pi i \cdot trace((g+w)^T\cdot a\cdot (g+w) \cdot z)}$ is absolutely convergent and uniformly convergent on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ and that it is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$.

I have tried to adapt the proof that shows that the theta function is uniformly convergent, the problem for me was that the theta function sums over integers so we can uniformly majorize it by the geometric series, but what can we do if we sum over complex numbers in the definition of $f(w)$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.